# How to get all the HTML code generated via PHP at application-level

Tags: php, html, apache, dom

Is it possible, in PHP, to get all the generated HTML code, at the end of request processing?

What I want to achieve is to be able to retrieve (and, possibly, save/cache) the actual HTML that is about to be sent to users. I can do something similar in ASP.net with a Global.asax filter, that can access to low-level generated html code and modify/access it.

If needed, I can modify the web server settings and/or php interpreter settings (currently the web application runs on Apache+mod_php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
<?php
// Start buffering (no output delivered to the browser from now on)
ob_start();

// Generate the HTML
// ...

// Grab the buffer as a variable
$html_output = ob_get_contents();

// If you want to stop buffering and send the buffer to the browser
ob_end_flush();
// OR if you want to stop buffering and throw away the buffer
ob_end_clean();
```

**Potential issues**

There is a potential user impact as (depending on your web server) your page output is streamed to the user's browser as it's outputted (why you can start seeing really large pages before they've finished loading). But if you use the output buffer the user will only see the result after you've stopped buffering and outputted it.

Also, because you're buffering and not streaming your server will need to store what you're buffering which will use up additional memory (not a problem unless you're generating really large pages that exceed the memory limits of your PHP memory limit).

To avoid running out of memory you can chunk your buffering and write it to disc (or flush it to the user) at specific chunk sizes using a callback like this:

```
<?php
// The callback function each time we want to deal with a chunk of the buffer
$callback = function ($buffer, $flag) {

    // Cache the next part of the buffer to file?
    file_put_contents('page.cache', $buffer, FILE_APPEND & LOCK_EX);

    // $flag contains which action is performing the callback.
    // We could be ending due to the final flush and not because
    // the buffer size limit  was reached. PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_END
    // means an ob_end_*() function has been called.
    if ($flag == PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_END) {
       // Do something different
    }

    // We could echo out this chunk if we want
    echo $buffer;

    // Whatever we return from this function is the new buffer
    return '';
};

// Pass the buffer to $callback each time it reaches 1024 bytes
ob_start($callback, 1024)

// Generate the HTML
// ...

ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Thanks! (and thanks to RamRaider too); I think this is exactly what I needed. Just some questions: does it slows down the requests? And, can I make the ob_start() default for *all* php scripts, without having to manually add it in each page/controller of the web application?

Comment: Added potential issues to the answer. As for enabling it for all php scripts, do you have a central page that all your web requests go through? If so, you can do it through that. Otherwise I recommend you create one that does wrap your other scripts and handles the buffering.

Comment: Thanks again; very helpful. I read that I can also specify the chunk_size in ob_start(); and the output buffer will be automatically flushed to client when it exceeds the set chunk size. But, is it possibile to intercept the moment when the output is to be flushed, and append it to a variable before it's flushed?

Comment: @CarmineGiangregorio Yes. You can specify a callback as the first parameter of the `ob_start` function. I'll mock up an example in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you would want to use is output buffering! At the start of your page use: ob_start();
At the end of the page you send to the client / browser using something like : ob_end_flush();

Before it is sent you can record that buffer to the db or text file